# Share: Getting 'Forbidden' message when sharing externally

Tags: entry

I've run into an odd issue and I can't seem to figure out what is going on.

**Normal Process:**

1. I click the Share arrow on a disabled entry.
2. I copy the tokenized link and send it out.
3. Folks without accounts are able to preview the page.

**What is happening now:**

1. I click the Share arrow on a disabled entry.
2. I copy the tokenized link and send it out.
3. Folks without accounts are given a 'Forbidden' warning. If I refresh my preview page, I also get the same warning.

*NOTES: There is no authentication required to access the template itself.*

I checked the latest updates to Craft but did not see anything obvious that might affect that. I double-checked that the token time extension that we added in general.php and it's still set to a week.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the Forbidden warning?  It sounds like it's coming from the web server instead of Craft.

Comment: Also, does the template you're trying to share have any sort of authentication logic in it?

Comment: @BradBell Updated, and no. It's just an article posting.

Comment: Hrm... is mod_security or Suhosin installed on that server?

Comment: @BradBell Nope.

Comment: Is `/en/index.php` the same entry point that Craft uses to load normal requests?  i.e. the rest of the site and the Control Panel loads fine?

Comment: @BradBell Yup! We can access the rest of the site and control panel items just fine. We only seem to encounter this error when we try to share a disabled entry.

Comment: I'm officially out of ideas. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ I can't imagine how a non-Craft authenticated request would cause an Apache 403 forbidden response.